# I faced a conflict in using DropShadow and Ripple

Tags: qt, qml, dropshadow, ripple-effect

I wrote a `Ripple` item in a `Rectangle` Item and enabled `clip` property of the Rectangle to prevent the Ripple drawing get out of that Rectangle.

without DropShadow:

[image: without DropShadow]

Everything works fine until I add a `DropShadow` to that Rectangle. Although it is outside the Rectangle item, but it neutralizes the clip effect in left and right side of the Rectangle.

with DropShadow:

[image: with DropShadow]

Here is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls.Material.impl 2.12

Item{
                    width: 400
                    height: 100

                    DropShadow {
                        anchors.fill: itemRect
                            horizontalOffset: 0
                            verticalOffset: 0
                            radius: 12.0
                            samples: 17
                            color: "#50000000"
                            source: itemRect
                        }

                    Rectangle{
                        id:itemRect
                        anchors.fill: parent;
                        anchors.margins: 8;
                        border.width: 1
                        radius: 5;
                        clip: true;


                        MouseArea{
                            id: button
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            onPressed: {
                                ripple.x=mouseX-(ripple.width/2);
                                ripple.y=mouseY-(ripple.height/2);
                            }


                            Ripple {
                                id: ripple
                                clipRadius: 2
                                x:40
                                width: itemRect.width*2
                                height: itemRect.height*2
                                pressed: button.pressed
                                active:  false
                                color: "#10000000"
//                                layer.enabled: true
//                                layer.effect: OpacityMask {
//                                            maskSource: Rectangle
//                                            {
//                                                width: ripple.height
//                                                height: ripple.height
//                                                radius: ripple.height
//                                            }
//                                        }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
```

I tested `OpacityMask` for `layer.effect` of Ripple Item. But it didn't have any effects.

Comment: I think we'd need to see the source code of Ripple in order to help. Even better would be an example that we can run and build that recreates the issue.

Comment: Yes you'r right, Ripple is not in documents. I think it designed to use in special places, not everywhere.

Comment: I'm going to write my own Ripple library :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly i wrote my own Ripple.
It can be used anywhere without any issues.

https://github.com/mmjvox/Another-Ripple

here is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12
import AnotherRipple 1.0

Item{
                    width: 400
                    height: 100

                    DropShadow {
                        anchors.fill: itemRect
                            horizontalOffset: 0
                            verticalOffset: 0
                            radius: 12.0
                            samples: 17
                            color: "#50000000"
                            source: itemRect
                        }

                    Rectangle{
                        id:itemRect
                        anchors.fill: parent;
                        anchors.margins: 8;
                        border.width: 1
                        radius: 5;
                        clip: true;
                        
                        SimpleRipple{
                            id: ripple
                            anchors.fill: parent;
                            color: "#50ffa070"
                        }

                        MouseArea{
                            id: button
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            onClicked: {

                                // In this example MouseArea accepts pressed event to provide clicked(released) event.
                                // Ripple can't sense pressed event, so I called pressed method of Ripple.
                        
                                ripple.pressed(mouse.x,mouse.y);
                                
                                // Some Other Operations
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I wrote a library and use that instead of `QtQuick.Controls.Material.impl` library. I'll edit my answer and add a sample code to explain my solution